# Error "UTF-8" in Sever and Client Android when decode - encode?

Tags: javascript, android, utf-8, decode, encode

I have an error when username in my app on android. I use TomCat server and Eclipse.

My code in Client:

```
    String name = "Quân";
    Debug.e("1" + name);
    try {
        url = URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
        Debug.e("2" + url);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Debug.e("3" + URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    client = new WebSocketClient(URI.create(WsConfig.URL_WEBSOCKET
            + url), new WebSocketClient.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnect() {

        }

        /**
         * On receiving the message from web socket server
         * */
        @Override
        public void onMessage(String message) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Got string message! %s", message));

            parseMessage(message);

        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(byte[] data) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Got binary message! %s",
                    bytesToHex(data)));

            // Message will be in JSON format
            parseMessage(bytesToHex(data));
        }

        /**
         * Called when the connection is terminated
         * */
        @Override
        public void onDisconnect(int code, String reason) {

            String message = String.format(Locale.US,
                    "Disconnected! Code: %d Reason: %s", code, reason);

            showToast(message);

            // clear the session id from shared preferences
            utils.storeSessionId(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error! : " + error);

            showToast("Error! : " + error);
        }

    }, null);

    client.connect();
    return view;
}
```

> 09-09 08:43:51.265 5838-5838/vtvlive.vn.barcaquan E/Tag MainFragment.java.onCreateView():92: 1Quân
>
> 09-09 08:43:51.265 5838-5838/vtvlive.vn.barcaquan E/Tag MainFragment.java.onCreateView():95: 2Qu%C3%A2n
>
> 09-09 08:43:51.266 5838-5838/vtvlive.vn.barcaquan E/Tag MainFragment.java.onCreateView():100: 3Quân

For name "Quân", serverside threw to me this:

```
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {

    System.out.println(session.getId() + " has opened a connection");

    Map<String, String> queryParams = getQueryMap(session.getQueryString());

    String name = "";

    if (queryParams.containsKey("name")) {

        // Getting client name via query param
        name = queryParams.get("name");
        System.out.println("1"+name);
        try {
            name = URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("2"+name);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Mapping client name and session id
        nameSessionPair.put(session.getId(), name);
    }
```

> > 0 has opened a connection
> >
> > 1QuÃ¢n
> >
> > 2QuÃ¢n

Any suggestions how to solve it?